# Folders to 404 page on server

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a site where it contains some folders which currently simply list the contents (which I do not want to do).

I could simply stick a index file in them however was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do this using the htaccess file.

So for example I want `http://localhost:8888/includes/` to go to `http://localhost:8888/404.php`

**BUT**

Need `http://localhost:8888/includes/header.php` and `http://localhost:8888/assets/img/head.png` to still work correctly

Cheers :)

Comment: Maybe this directive `Options -Indexes` in the .htaccess file will be useful. It stops listing of directories.

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# request is for a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# there is no index.html inside requested directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
# redirect to /404.php
RewriteRule ^ /404.php [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code on your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^8888$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/includes/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}:%{SERVER_PORT}/404.php
```